# How to import a dyamic list of files in python?

Tags: python, import

I'm trying this code but it's giving me an error. I would like to loop through the files and have access to some variables.

First thing I did was count the number of files in a directory and try to loop from there.
Example:

```
Sample_External_DIR_content (not in the code just showing sample content of DIR)  = [myfile0, myfile1, myfile2]
Code:
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/some_directory/some_directory/'
num_of_files = [code to get number of files from DIR]
for i in range(0,number_of_files):
    from myfile + str[i] import some_variable
```

Is there a similar way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific on what you need?

Comment: This line here is giving me a syntax error #from myfile + str[i] import some variable. I just like to have access to some_variables in those modules. If I have one to two files then from myfile0, myfile1 import some_variable would be fine but what if I have many then i have to write all those. But if i can loop or do something similar to what I'm trying to do then that would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `__import__` function which allows you to import a module given a string:

```
>>> django = __import__('django')
>>> django.get_version()
'1.5.4'
>>>
```

In your case:

```
variables = []
for i in range(0,number_of_files):
    variables.append(__import__(myfile + str[i]).some_variable)
```

Be careful, you need to have `some_variable` in each module in this case. You can also check with `dir` to see if your variable exists in the module before trying to access to it...

```
>>> dir(django)
['VERSION', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'get_version', 'utils']
```

See also: [More about Python imports.](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)